# c++ split and foreach array

Tags: c++, arrays, string

how can I split (with ,) a string and match every element?
I'm using gcc version 4.6.3 on Ubuntu.

My "pseudo-code":

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char str[] = "foo,bar";
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (str,",");

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i) {
       if( pch[i] == "something" ) {
          cout << pch[i] << "\r\n";
       }
   }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: @Mgetz that question asks about splitting strings by whitespace.

Comment: @TimSeguine scroll down to the second answer

Comment: @Mgetz I know, I read it. But as I understand it a question is a duplicate if the *question* is duplicated, not if the answers are applicable.

Comment: Why does your question title have the words "foreach array"? I don't understand how that is relevant to the question you asked in the post.

Comment: @TimSeguine the question is how to split a string in C++, the delimiter should be irrelevant ultimately.

Comment: @Mgetz but if you mark it a duplicate as is, it would most likely only confuse people, since the accepted answer only splits on whitespace, which is precisely what was asked for in that question.

Comment: @TimSeguine http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231212/226653

Comment: @Mgetz I am familiar with that post, but in my opinion that doesn't apply since the **accepted answer** to that question won't solve this OP's problem. It's more like "many questions have similar or identical answers but are not duplicates". I agree that the proper solution to both problems does not depend on the delimiter. I don't feel like arguing about this further, I am only explaining why I don't think this should be flagged. I doesn't bother me if you wanted to.

Comment: @user476918 I gave you a ready to use solution. Do not take into account that some idiots downvoted my answer.:)

Answer (score -3):

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char str[] = "foo,something,bar";

    char *p = std::strtok( str, "," );
    while ( p )
    {
        if ( std::strcmp( p, "something" ) == 0 ) std::cout << p << std::endl;
        p = std::strtok( NULL, "," );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :)

```
something
```

An other approach is to use class `std::string` and `std::istringstream`. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main() 
{
    char str[] = "foo,something,bar";
    std::istringstream is( str );
    std::string word;

    while ( std::getline( is, word, ',' ) )
    {
        if ( word == "something" ) std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output will be the same as above.

If you need to store separate words then you can use class `std::vector<std::string>` to store them.

Comment: this could be massively improved by say including a C++ not largely C answer that was thread safe as `strtok` is most definitely not

Comment: @Mgetz I am sure he is not interesting in threads.

Comment: I absolutely wouldn't make that assumption, the last thing you want as a developer is to find out later that your code isn't thread safe.

Comment: `strtok` should be killed with fire IMO

Comment: `strtok` should be killed with fire.